What is the fastest way to rasterize a triangle?
I'm making a triangle rasterizer for my 3d engine because I forgot to make a depth buffer and I was wondering what is the fastest way to rasterize a triangle,
I was thinking bresenham combined with another algorithm I found in this video (skip to 6:47) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PahbNFypubE&t=437s for horizontal slopes
or I could use bresenham but clear out the useless points to make it easier to draw pixels with lines for every y coordinate
let me know if you have better ideas and even better, benchmarked them

What do you mean by “I forgot to make a depth buffer”? How do you handle overlapping triangles?

I made a camera and mesh loader and stuff but and instead of using a depth buffer i just sorted the triangles by distance and forgot that some triangle can go through eachother
